# Always show Fotorama navigation

Tags: jquery, fotorama

It is obvious for me to always show the arrows and the full screen icon.

The problem is, that the icons are shown when you hover the gallery by standard. I don’t want this standard, because this leads to the problem that it is not possible to open the full screen mode on the mobile phone.

Currently I am using Fotorama 4.4.4.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use `data-arrows="always"`

Comment: This attribute still does not have the desired effect, while the css solution below works.

Answer (score 0):

Put this portion off CSS somewhere in *your* styles, after `fotorama.css`:

```
.fotorama__arr,
.fotorama__fullscreen-icon {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}

.fotorama__arr--disabled {
    opacity: .1 !important;
}

.fotorama__wrap--video .fotorama__arr,
.fotorama__wrap--video .fotorama__fullscreen-icon {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artpolikarpov/Txgbm/